# How do say “to post” in the context of social media?

Tags: single-word-requests

Which verb should is use to mean “to post” in the sense of posting to Instagram, Twitter, Facebook, etc?

The dictionary doesn’t really give a outright meaning that is close to what I’m trying to convey.

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE]! Can you indicate which dictionary / which dictionaries you mean by "the dictionary"? To do so, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 4):

I usually translate that with the verb "afiŝi". [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=afi%C5%9D) also supports this usage.